# Sort array with date as string by upcoming dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6

So I am trying to sort an array so that the first item would be the same as the current day and month or the closest entry.

My array looks like this:

```
[
    [
       "Firstname Lastname",
        "1979-01-03",
        "40"
    ],
    [
        "Firstname Lastname",
        "1996-01-23",
        "23"
    ],
    [
        "Firstname Lastname",
        "1977-01-28",
        "41"
    ],
    [
        "Firstname Lastname",
        "1983-03-11",
        "35"
    ],
    [
       "Firstname Lastname",
       "1977-03-30",
        "41"
    ],
    [
       "Firstname Lastname",
        "1975-05-08",
        "43"
    ]
]
```

I did figure out how to sort the array based on the day of the month but then it ignores the month itself

```
relativeYearDay(date) {
    let differenceDay = new Date(date).getDate() - new Date().getDate();

     if (differenceDay < 0) {
         differenceDay += 365;
     }

     return differenceDay;
}

getUpcomingBirthdays() {
     return this.birthdays.slice(0).sort((a, b) => {
         return this.relativeYearDay(a[1]) - this.relativeYearDay(b[1]);
    });
},
```

Like I mentioned this returns a sorted array based on the day of the month.

How would I do it for both day and month?

Comment: So you're trying to sort the array by date, ignoring year? If your format was consistent, just chop off the first 5 characters of the string (`"yyyy-"`) and sort by what's left.

Comment: Transform the date to timestamp and sort it using that.

Comment: 'Math.round(new Date("2013/09/05 15:34:00").getTime()/1000)'

Comment: Does "closest entry" look backwards? IE, would January 22nd be the closest, or furthest, value from January 23rd?

Comment: @MerakMarey Sorting using timestamp would not ignore year.

Comment: @TylerRoper It will if you use a fixed year at the time of the new Date object creation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, since you want to sort by next birthdays, you can set the current year to all the `dates` when comparing to the `current date`. When the difference between they is negative (i.e birthday already occurs), you can add an offset of 1 year from now.

```js
const birthdays = [
    ["Firstname Lastname", "1979-01-03", "40"],
    ["Firstname Lastname", "1996-01-23", "23"],
    ["Firstname Lastname", "1977-01-28", "41"],
    ["Firstname Lastname", "1983-03-11", "35"],
    ["Firstname Lastname", "1977-03-30", "41"],
    ["Firstname Lastname", "1975-05-08", "43"]
];

function distanceToBirthday(date)
{
    let currDate = new Date();
    currDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    let currYear = currDate.getFullYear();

    let offset = new Date();
    offset.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    offset.setFullYear(currYear + 1);

    date = new Date(date + " 00:00");
    date.setFullYear(currYear);

    let diff = date - currDate;
    return (diff < 0) ? diff + offset.getTime() : diff;
}

function getUpcomingBirthdays(bdays)
{
    return bdays.slice(0).sort(
        (a, b) => distanceToBirthday(a[1]) - distanceToBirthday(b[1])
    );
}

console.log(getUpcomingBirthdays(birthdays));
```

Comment: Thanks! This and @michael-lynch answer are nearly the same! This makes sense and works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Your original answer was very close.   When sorting you just need to figure out the date of the users NEXT upcoming birthday.

```js
const birthdays = [
    [ "Firstname Lastname", "1979-01-03", "40" ],
    [ "Firstname Lastname", "1996-01-23", "23" ],
    [ "Firstname Lastname", "1977-01-28", "41" ],
    [ "Firstname Lastname", "1983-03-11", "35" ],
    [ "Firstname Lastname", "1977-03-30", "41" ],
    [ "Firstname Lastname", "1975-05-08", "43" ]
];


function getNextBirthday(date) {
    // Current Date
    let currentDate = new Date();

    // Set the users birthday to this year (originally from thier birth year)
    let birthday = new Date(date);
    birthday.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear());

    // If the birthday has already occured this year.  Then thier next birthday is next year.
    if (birthday - currentDate < 0) {
        birthday.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    }

    // Return the users next birthday as a date.
    return birthday;
}

function getUpcomingBirthdays() {
     return birthdays.slice(0).sort((a, b) => {
         return getNextBirthday(a[1]) - getNextBirthday(b[1]);
    });
}
```

*Edit: Added comments & fix small bug in code.*

Answer (score 0):

I misread the question and thought you wanted just the nearest to the current date.

In simple coding... and may give you some ideas to turn it into a sorting routine

```js
const data = [
    [
       "Firstname Lastname",
        "1979-01-03",
        "40"
    ],
    [
        "Firstname Lastname",
        "1996-01-23",
        "23"
    ],
    [
        "Firstname Lastname",
        "1977-01-28",
        "41"
    ],
    [
        "Firstname Lastname",
        "1983-03-11",
        "35"
    ],
    [
       "Firstname Lastname",
       "1977-03-30",
        "41"
    ],
    [
       "Firstname Lastname",
        "1975-05-08",
        "43"
    ]
];
const now = new Date().getTime();
let nearestIndex = -1;
let nearest = 0;

data.forEach( (item, index) => {
  if(nearest ==0 || now-new Date(item[1]).getTime() < nearest) {
    nearest = now-new Date(item[1]).getTime();
    nearestIndex = index;
  }  
});

console.log(`Nearest date is at index ${nearestIndex}`, data[nearestIndex], nearest, nearestIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array by an sorting algorithm with sections, where you take a date as separator and move smaller values to the end of the array, and sort all other by date.

This approach uses the a part string, because [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates are sortable by string.

```js
var array = [["Firstname Lastname", "1979-01-03", "40"], ["Firstname Lastname", "1996-01-23", "23"], ["Firstname Lastname", "1977-01-28", "41"], ["Firstname Lastname", "1983-03-11", "35"], [ "Firstname Lastname","1977-03-30", "41"], [ "Firstname Lastname", "1975-05-08", "43"]],
    day = (new Date).toISOString().slice(5, 10)

array.sort(({ 1: a }, { 1: b }) =>
    (a.slice(5) < day) - (b.slice(5) < day) || a.slice(5).localeCompare(b.slice(5)));

console.log(array.map(a => a.join(' | ')));
```